# How to REPLACE html tags with characters using jsoup in java

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup

I am using a java code to extract information from the web for processing, and I am using the `jsoup` library to clean the html tags in the responses I get from website. Now in order to extract info from these codes I have to replace the html tags with a rarely used character such as '~'.

So here's my question:

How do I convert this:

```
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>
```

Into this:

```
   ~This is heading 1~
   ~This is heading 2~
   ~This is heading 3~
   ~This is heading 4~
   ~This is heading 5~
   ~This is heading 6~
```

using `jsoup`?

Comment: modify org.jsoup.safety.Cleaner ??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: i tried a ceratin method but it only replaced contents inside a tag...not the entire tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String cssSelector = //add your selector. from the example you include i cant get a proper selector.
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("html")
Elements elms = doc.select(cssSelector)
for(Element elm:elms){
     System.out.println("~" + elm.text() + "~")
}
```

## update

if you want to replace **ALL** elements you can do this:

```
html = html.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","~")
```

Comment: probably, what are you trying to select? can you post a sample of the html?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble..this is the first time I'm using Jsoup

Comment: so what elements do you want to select, theres not h1,h2 in there

Comment: I wanna replace ALL the HTML tags with '~'

Comment: i thought you wanted to replace specifc elements.

Comment: oh no ...i wanna replace all of em...the above one was just an example

Comment: sorry never done that before maybe something like html.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","~") should normaly work

Comment: thats what you want ? `~~~47~~21~~68~~~P~~~~~~Advanced Communication Lab. (10ECL67)~~~21~~15~~36~~~P~~~~~~Microprocessor Lab. (10ECL68)~~~36~~13~~49~~~P~~~~~~~~~~Semester:~~~~5~~~~~ `

Comment: yea..thats exactly what i want

Comment: then this regex would do it html.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","~"), i am not sure if is the best choice to go for regex or parser in this case, but if your html is not very big it should be fine.